# ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Regression with K-Fold model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, regression, k-fold

I am trying out to run this code from François Chollet's Book "Deep Learning with Python" (chapter 3, regression part).

```py
from keras.datasets import boston_housing

(train_data, train_targets), (test_data, test_targets) = boston_housing.load_data()

mean = train_data.mean(axis=0)
train_data -= mean

std = train_data.std(axis=0)
train_data /= std

test_data -= mean
test_data /= std

def build_model():
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(64 , activation='relu', input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(64 , activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    return model

k = 4
num_val_samples = len(train_data)
num_epochs = 100
all_scores = []


for i in range(k):
    print('processing fold #', i)

    val_data = train_data[i * num_val_samples:(i+1) * num_val_samples]
    val_targets = train_targets[i * num_val_samples:(i+1) * num_val_samples]

    partial_train_data = np.concatenate(
        [train_data[:i*num_val_samples],
         train_data[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]],
         axis=0)
    partial_train_targets = np.concatenate(
        [train_targets[:i*num_val_samples],
         train_targets[(i+1) * num_val_samples:]], 
         axis=0)

    model = build_model()

    model.fit(partial_train_data,
            partial_train_targets,
            epochs=num_epochs,
            batch_size=1,
            verbose=0)

    val_mse, val_mae = model.evaluate(val_data,val_targets,verbose=0)
    print(all_scores.append(val_mae))

print(np.mean(all_scores))
```

I got this error :

```
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.
```

I didn't find out why I got this error. I've tried to add **run_eagerly=True** to the compile function. I got the same result. Also, the book is from 2017, so maybe some function works a bit differently nowadays (I hope not).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've found the issue. There is an error in my code. I need to divide the data length by the number of folds else validation arrays would not have proper boundaries.
`num_val_samples = len(train_data) // k`